# After close application shared pref Boolean value is false

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In splash screen check the condition, if the condition is false Dialog box will appear.
In Dial log box, if the user is accept condition shared preference Boolean will true If user click cancels SharedPref Boolean value will false.
Once the user accepts the condition, no Need show dialog box in the feature open application.

For me opens the application dialog box is coming, Because always "**False**" Boolean value is coming.
I could not able to understand where I did mistake,
Could you please help me.

```
Boolean value is getting false every time.
public static final String Alert_Dialog = "AlertDialog";
static SharedPreferences settings;
public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
settings=getSharedPreferences(Alert_Dialog, 0);
    editor = settings.edit();
if(settings.getBoolean("Alert_Dialog", false)==false){
Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this,"False cond=="+settings.getBoolean("Alert_Dialog", false),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            UserAgreement();
    }else if(settings.getBoolean("Alert_Dialog", false)==true){
Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this,"True cond=="+settings.getBoolean("Alert_Dialog", false),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Intent intentHActivity = new Intent(this, HActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentHActivity);
    }

@SuppressLint("StringFormatInvalid")
private void UserAgreement() {

    final Dialog openDialog1 = new Dialog(context);
    openDialog1.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_box_layout);
    Button dialogAgreeButton = (Button)openDialog1.findViewById(R.id.dialog_agree_button);
    TextView cancleTV1= (TextView)openDialog1.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancle_tv);
dialogAgreeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editor.putBoolean("Alert_Dialog", true);               Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this,"accept==="+settings.getBoolean("Alert_Dialog", false),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    cancleTV1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editor.putBoolean("Alert_Dialog", false);
            Toast.makeText(SActivity.this,"cancle==="+settings.getBoolean("Alert_Dialog", false),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            finish();
        }
    });

    openDialog1.show();
    openDialog1.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


    openDialog1.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
    editor.commit();

}
```

Comment: Is getting mean goes?

Comment: Sorry for my English. I improving my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `dialogAgreeButton.setOnClickListener()` You just forgot to  to commit your changes  in `SharedPreferences`

## Use [**`editor.apply();`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply()) OR [`editor.commit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#commit())  to commit changes in `SharedPreferences`

**FYI**

> Whenever your change the value in `SharedPreferences` use [`commit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#commit()) or [`apply()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply()) to Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the `SharedPreferences` object it is editing

Change your code like this

```
dialogAgreeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editor.putBoolean("Alert_Dialog", true);   
            editor.apply();   
            Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this,"accept==="+settings.getBoolean("Alert_Dialog", false),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank You Nilesh for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should commit after putting something in shared preference like this `editor.apply()`

```
       public void onClick(View v) {
            editor.putBoolean("Alert_Dialog", true); 
            editor.apply()                  

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
```

Note: **editor.apply()** immediately after editor.putBoolean("Alert_Dialog", true)

Comment: Thank you minhazur  for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The Editor.commit() call is done before the actual putBoolean.
The putBoolean is only called onClick, but the commit call is already executed when the dialog appears, which is before any changes have been made.
Just call it like `editor.putBoolean("Alert_Dialog", false).commit()` and you will be fine.